# when using zurb foundation orbit slider, how to center slides

Tags: css, zurb-foundation, orbit

as shown in this screenshot:
[image: extra wide screen causes background to show through]
on my 24" monitor the white background shows through my orbit slider.
This is because my source image is narrower (in pixels) than the browser window's width.

If I make my window narrower, the image scales down as one would expect, without any background showing through:
[image: no background when window is 1600px wide or narrower]

What I would like to accomplish is to center the `<li>` elements that make up the slides so that when the image is narrower it won't have dumb looking white stripe on one side.
[image: browser inspector showing ul/li elements]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

Set up a class of full_width with the following style:

```
.full_width {
    width:100%;}
```

Add this class to the orbit ul:

```
<ul class="full_width" data-orbit data-options="...">
   <li><img src="img/slider/slide1.png"></li>
   <li><img src="img/slider/slide2.png"></li>
   <li><img src="img/slider/slide3.png"></li>
   <li><img src="img/slider/slide4.png"></li>
</ul>
```

Then in your style sheet add a class of full_width li img and set the width of your images and add margin: 0 auto like:

```
.full_width li img {
    width:960px;
    margin:0 auto;}
```

Comment: I should say, on the '.full_width li img` class I only needed the margin.